# if vlookup return nothing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Below Is my Vlookup Formula

=VLOOKUP(setup!$G$6,setup!$B$6:$C$21,2,0)

Where setup is the excel sheet i am referring to get the data.I just want to Find in case if vlookup doesn't return anything,than that cell should return String "Bye".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formula `IFERROR`, like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(setup!$G$6,setup!$B$6:$C$21,2,0),"Bye")
```

It returns anything you set in the second argument in case the first argument returns na error.

If the formula is capturing a blank cell, `VLOOKUP` will return "0" instead of "" (empty).

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(setup!$G$6,setup!$B$6:$C$21,2,0)=0,"Bye",VLOOKUP(setup!$G$6,setup!$B$6:$C$21,2,0))
```

Comment: It is returning 0

Comment: the value where the data comes from is blank

Comment: pnuts- Syntax Error

Comment: Share your table. It'll be easier to figure out what's going on!

Comment: Shared Please See the answer

Comment: @Julio.L.Muller - Sorry but I cannot upvote without an IFERROR wrapper on the second formula solution.